# Show That There Is One and (Essentially) Only One Field With 3 Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

My thought process is the following: By default, 0 and 1 have to be in this set of 3 elements since they are the neutral additive and neutral multiplicative elements, respectfully. So the set of the 3 elements that make up this field must be {0,1,x}. But for any element "a" in the set, there must be some "-a" element such that a + (-a) = 0. Therefore there is only one option for x; x=-1. My set must then be {-1,0,1}. Is this correct? It seems too simple, so I wanted a second opinion.

Comment: It is right ... but what have it to do with real analysis?

Comment: I think using the word isomorphism might be helpful.

Comment: What does this have to do with real analysis? It looks like algebra to me.

Comment: The name of the book that our class is using is called "Introduction to analysis".

Comment: No, it is *not* right. What if $1+1=0$ and $x$ is another element? You have to handle the case where $(-1)=1$. @user251257

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well we need to have that $x+1$ is one of $0,1,x$. If $x+1=0$ then $x=-1$ since inverses are unique. If $x+1=1$ then $x=0$, which means we don't have three elements. If $x+1=x$ then $1=0$, which means the field is trivial. So we need to have $x=-1$ necessarily. In your example, we'd then have $x=1$ and the field has only two elements. So it's not a counterexample.

Comment: Punchline: French Toast is correct. But this still isn't a real analysis question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm a bit confused. I'm not sure why 1+1 would ever be equal to 0. There is probably some explanation to what you're suggesting, but so far we have only had two lectures in this course and nowhere in the book leading up to this homework assignment does it mention anything similar to what you're suggesting.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch look up $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo 2. That's a field with two elements, which has $1+1=0$.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch $\mathbb Z_2$ is a field, and $1+1=0$ there. There are many other fields where $1+1=0$ - they are called "fields of characteristic $2$." You can show that a field of three elements can't be a field of characteristic $2$, but that is part of this question. The definition of a field never indicated that $(-x)$ was different from $x$.

Comment: @JahanClaes : Oh, I understand now. So if we had Z in modulo 5 then we would have things like 4+1 = 0, right? 
I think we're just dealing with regular sets in this course for now. For the intents and purposes of this particular problem, I think my answer is correct.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch in a couple of weeks you're going to realize that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are just about the most regular sets around. You should really try to understand why your reasoning is faulty, it will pay off down the road.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You are actually missing the point of the definitions - the above field you are creating with three elements is exactly the field of $\mathbb Z$ modulo $3$. So if you are counting the field of two elements as "not a regular set," whatever that means, then you are also calling the field of $3$ elements  "not a regular set." The key to getting math is reading and understanding the definition. @FrenchToastCrunch

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch I'm afraid I agree with the others that you are assuming something which is part of the question. You might do better to consider the element $1+x$ - what is that equal to? There are three possibilities, and you should be able to eliminate two of them.

Comment: People here have a *lot* of mathematical experience, and this is a very standard problem, @FrenchToastCrunch Saying "I know what the teacher wants here" is being myopic. Try reading and understanding the people here trying to help you, and don't make assumptions.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch Something to think about: In your 3-element field, what does $1+1$ equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is correct, your reasoning is not. I realize you're new to abstract algebra, so I'll just say this: when we write down things like $1$ and $0$, we mean only that these things *are the multiplicative and additive identities*, respectively. We do NOT think of them as subsets of the real line. For example, we can define a perfectly good field with only two elements $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$ where multiplication is defined as usual, and addition is *defined* as $1+1=0$.

Now, we want to show that there's only one field with three elements. We know $0$ and $1$ must be in this field, and that $0\neq 1$. So if we call the remaining element $x$, we have to find if there is more than one possible thing for $x$ to be.

We know, by closure, that $x+1$ has to be in our field, so either $x+1=0$, $x+1=1$, or $x+1=x$. In the first case, we get $x=-1$, where by $-1$ I do NOT mean "negative one", but rather simply "the additive inverse of one". In the second case we get $x=0$, which is wrong because we want $x$ to be a NEW element of our set. In the third case, we get $1=0$, which is also bad. So we know $x=-1$!

Now, we still haven't fully determined our field. Why? Well, we know there's only one possible third element, but we still have to fully define what addition does on the elements. In particular, we want to show that there's only ONE way to define addition on the elements consistent with the field axioms. We already know what happens if you take $1+0$, $1+-1$, and $-1+0$. We just need to figure out what happens when you take $1+1$ and $-1+-1$. We know $1+1$ has to be in our set, so $1+1=1,0,-1$. If $1+1=1$ then $1=0$, if $1+1=0$ then $-1=1$ and there's only two elements in your field. So $1+1=-1$. Similarly, $-1+-1=1$. Then you just have to check there's only one way to define multiplication (there is), and you're done.

Comment: Hmm, I see. This type of reasoning is very different from what I'm used to. Are there any good videos online for this subject that you can recommend? There is very little online that I could find. The name of my course is technically "advanced calculus", but we use an "analysis" book.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch There's video series about abstract algebra online (see, e.g.,  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146774/khan-academy-for-abstract-algebra)). But in general, I would just read the wikipedia articles on groups, rings, and fields, paying particular attention to the examples.