# Addition table for a finit field with 3 elements $\mathbb{F}_{3}=\{0,1,-1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

just a quick question :-)

I need to make an addition table for a finit field with 3 elements $\mathbb{F}_{3}=\{0,1,-1\}$

Is this table correct?

$ \begin{matrix}
\boldsymbol{\textbf{+}} & \mathbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{-1} \\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{0}} & 0 & 1 & -1\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{1}} & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{-1}} & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix}$

@ZeroTheHero:

$ \begin{matrix}
\boldsymbol{\textbf{+}} & \mathbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} \\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{0}} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{1}} & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{2}} & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{matrix}$

Comment: So $1+(-1)=1{}{}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i would say so. The -1 confuses me...

Comment: But that is what you wrote in your table.

Comment: yeah i meant the -1 in the finit field. But this could also be 0.

Comment: @hukachaka -1=2 mod 3 so you could use 2 instead.  (And I don’t think your table is correct.)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero i dont know if i am allowed to use this. Do you think it is ok to do the table that way and replace all 2's afterwards?

Comment: @hukachaka methinks it’s simpler to think of $\mathbb{F}_3$ as the integers mod 3 i.e. $\{0,1,2\}$..

Comment: hmm ok i will update the table. gimme a few minutes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero i updated my post

Comment: ¿$1+1 = 0$? $1+1 = -1$

Comment: the -1 is confusing :-/ if this would be 2 and we would do mod 3 then the result of 1+1 would be 2.

Comment: @hukachaka How is $-1$ confusing? If you let $x=1+1$ then you have three choices for $x$. Is it $0$ or $1$ or $-1$? Eliminate the impossible.

Comment: @hukachaka that seems to work.  You can "trade back" your 2 to a -1 if you want.  Note that your second table will not be as your first.

Comment: Well, in $\Bbb{F}_3$ we have $2=-1$. So, of course, you can write $2$ in place of $-1$ everywhere (well, not in an exponent, because exponents are usual integers, but that doesn't apply here).

Answer (score 0):

You can't say that 1+(-1) = 0 = 1
So this is wrong because this 'field' now only has 2 elements, and also, a field requires that 1!=0. The alternative is that the -1 is an abuse of notation is not referring to additive inverse of 1, in which case this field is stupid lol. Theres only one possible way to define F_3 I'm pretty sure. [Show That There Is One and (Essentially) Only One Field With 3 Elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407235/show-that-there-is-one-and-essentially-only-one-field-with-3-elements/1407257)